# Can I use MPC when entering the USA with a travel visa?

Tags: usa, canada, working-visas

I am a Canadian national with a TN-1 visa to work in the USA. The lines at passport control are always a huge pain. I want to use the [Mobile Passport Control](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/mobile-passport-control) app to bypass the line.

It says that Canadian passport holders are eligible to use it, but at the airport, work visa holders have to line up with the non-Canadian visitors. Entering the "wrong way" on a TN status means that your status changes to the visitor visa instead, which I obviously don't want.

I can't find anything conclusive about eligibility for this app for a Canadian with a work visa.

Comment: The [CBP page on this](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/mobile-passport-control) says that it's open to Canadian "visitors," which probably implies B-status visitors (that is, visitors for "business" or "pleasure").  Further clarity is not to be had on that page, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

The [Mobile Passport App](https://www.mobilepassport.us/) site states on its [FAQ page](https://www.mobilepassport.us/faq/) that Canadians can use it to enter in B1 or B2 status.

> The Mobile Passport app may be used by U.S. citizens with a valid U.S. passport and Canadian citizens with both a valid Canadian passport and B1 or B2 visa status.

The CBP web site only says "Canadian visitors," which is probably crystal clear to a CBP officer, but not necessarily to ordinary people or infrequent travelers.

Answer (score 4):

This is also verified by an email with the CBP info centre:

> U.S. citizens and Canadian visitors can use Mobile Passport Control. Travelers must have a smart phone that can connect to the Internet or mobile network.. As a TN visa holder you are not considered a visitor and therefore you cannot use the CBP Mobile Passport Control app.

No you can’t use the CBP app.

Answer (score 1):

MPC is useless for TN visa holders. The CBP queue at Toronto Pearson is lengthy especially on Mondays. Air Canada makes it even tougher by restricting travellers not to check in not earlier than two hours before departure time. But United Airline doesn’t have that restriction. So, if you travel by Air Canada, good luck!

Comment: security check-in*

Comment: Hey @Jack Nick, you can edit your answer by pressing the "Edit" button on the bottom of your answer. Linked here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/176767/edit